# how to code relationship between objects and list of objects

Tags: oop, class

I am new to object oriented programming and learning to design classes.

I am wondering how can i design a class which holds list of itself.

For example, I have a class named Game will following definition:

Game

- title
- description
- screenshot
- flash (holds flash game object)

I want to display list of games on a page. What approach is good for it? 
Either create another class GameList and create array of Games to be listed or
create a function Game.ListAll to display game list?

I feel former is better approach to do so. I need your guide please.
Also i dont know what to actually study to clear my concepts in designing class and their relationships etc. 
Can you please suggest me a book CBT which is easy to understand ?

Thank you very much.

-Navi

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what languague your are using but I can recommend "Agile Priciples, Pattens and Practices" from Robert C. Martin (there is a C# version too). There is a lot about OO design in there too, together with all the important patterns and a nice intro to TDD and Agile - and it's fun to read.

To your question: yes go for your first idea or use a inbuild collection like `List<Game>` (should be the same no matter if you are using C# or Jave)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a bad design to have a (static) method `listAll()` within Game: Games shouldn't know about other games, you would need the constructors or factory methods to take care of the list, and you couldn't handle separate lists.

So use a **list outside of Game**. If you do not need special behavior of the GameList, a field List where you treat the list will do. If you have special behavior, your design with GameList is the right choice.

For good OO design, I would **read up** in the following order:

1. the relevant articles from the [object mentors article list](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/publishedArticles.html) to get an overview. You can find links to the most relevant for you at [principles of ood](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).
2. a book about design patterns, my favorite still being the classical [Design Patterns from the GoF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)
3. read [Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices from Uncle Bob](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135974445)